# Gathering information from ansible setup module and create a new inventory file

Tags: json, ansible

Imagine you have a simple inventory file with 1 group and more than 100 hosts.

```
[All]
server1
server2
.
.
.
server100
```

now I want to create more groups to use servers by OS , Major OS version or ... 
if we run :

```
# ansible server1 -m setup 

.
.
.
        "ansible_distribution": "CentOS", 
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "6", 
        "ansible_distribution_release": "Final", 
        "ansible_distribution_version": "6.5", 
.
.
.
.
```

so I create a new file using this command to have all servers information

```
# ansible All -m setup > all.out
```

the output is very like json so we assume this is a json file but not valid :

```
# jsonlint all.out 
[Error: Parse error on line 1:
server1 | SUCCESS => 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined']
```

for json parsing first I use this command :

```
grep -Po '(?<="ansible_hostname": ")[^"]*' all.out
```

first it works good but it have a problem i create this simple shellscript file :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do

        echo $(grep -Po '(?<="ansible_hostname": ")[^"]*')
        echo $(grep -Po '(?<="ansible_distribution": ")[^"]*')
        echo $(grep -Po '(?<="ansible_distribution_major_version": ")[^"]*')
        echo $(grep -Po '(?<="ansible_distribution_release": ")[^"]*')
        echo $(grep -Po '(?<="ansible_distribution_version": ")[^"]*')

done < all.out
```

but its only show hostname and other parameters are null 
i tryin to use python but because its not a valid json file it give errors too .

now question is do you know a better way to get required information from setup module and use that output to create a new inventory file with smaller groups ? 
do you know any switch or option we can pass to ansible and give a valid json ?

thank you .

Comment: "the output is very like json": sorry I lost you here. Ansible is python based so my guess is that is a python dict.

Comment: thank you as you said its very like json

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is probably to write a [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) script; rather than have a static ini file of hosts, your script will read in the hosts from somewhere else, then do all the processing to create groups and whatnot, and return all of that to Ansible.

In addition to the above documentation, there are [a bunch of examples](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/contrib/inventory) in the Ansible `contrib` directory.  The examples are all written in Python, but you can use any language you'd like as long as you can output a JSON structure on stdout.